Jax DNN library initialization failed
Main issue
I am trying to run a simple python test file that uses Jax with the following code:
import jax
key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
print(jax.device_count())

When I try to run this I get the error
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed.
Environment information
The full error is:
E1129 14:49:54.277288 3626746 cuda_dnn.cc:502] There was an error before creating cudnn handle (500): cudaErrorSymbolNotFound : named symbol not found
E1129 14:49:54.277657 3626746 cuda_dnn.cc:502] There was an error before creating cudnn handle (500): cudaErrorSymbolNotFound : named symbol not found
jax.errors.SimplifiedTraceback: For simplicity, JAX has removed its internal frames from the traceback of the following exception. Set JAX_TRACEBACK_FILTERI>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/thesis/jax_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/random.py", line 248, in PRNGKey
    return _return_prng_keys(True, _key('PRNGKey', seed, impl))
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/random.py", line 200, in _key
    return prng.random_seed(seed, impl=impl)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/prng.py", line 530, in random_seed
    seeds_arr = jnp.asarray(np.int64(seeds))
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 5592, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype=dtype, copy=bool(copy), order=order, device=device)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 5426, in array
    out_array: Array = lax_internal._convert_element_type(
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 587, in _convert_element_type
    return convert_element_type_p.bind(
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 2981, in _convert_element_type_b>
    operand = core.Primitive.bind(convert_element_type_p, operand,
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 438, in bind
    return self.bind_with_trace(find_top_trace(args), args, params)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 442, in bind_with_trace
    out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 955, in process_primitive
    return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)
  File "/vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 91, in apply_primitive
    outs = fun(*args)
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed. Look at the errors above for more details.

My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
The below information contains outputs for the commands

nvcc --version
conda list | grep cudnn
pip show nvidia-cudnn-cu12
nvidia-smi

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0
CUDNN
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         9.5.1.17                 pypi_0    pypi
pip show cudnn
Name: nvidia-cudnn-cu12
Version: 9.5.1.17
Summary: cuDNN runtime libraries
Home-page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone
Author: Nvidia CUDA Installer Team
Author-email: compute_installer@nvidia.com
License: NVIDIA Proprietary Software
Location: /vol/csedu-nobackup/project/cvgils/anaconda3/envs/graphcast/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: nvidia-cublas-cu12
Required-by: torch
NVIDIA-SMI
Fri Nov 29 14:08:04 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0     |

I am using a conda environment with python 3.10.
pip freeze gives me:
absl-py==2.1.0
ai-models==0.7.3
-e git+https://github.com/ecmwf-lab/ai-models-aurora.git@9f5022231d03cd92d0f2862caeb3c21e3629cca1#egg=ai_models_aurora
ai-models-fourcastnetv2==0.0.3
ai-models-graphcast==0.1.0
ai-models-panguweather==0.0.9
aiohappyeyeballs==2.4.0
annotated-types==0.7.0
array_api_compat==1.9.1
asciitree==0.3.3
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==24.2.0
backoff==2.2.1
blessed==1.20.0
cachetools==5.5.0
cads-api-client==1.5.1
Cartopy==0.24.1
cdsapi==0.7.4
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
cfgrib==0.9.14.1
cftime==1.6.4.post1
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
chex==0.1.87
click==8.1.7
cloudpickle==3.1.0
cmake==3.30.3
colabtools==0.0.1
coloredlogs==15.0.1
contourpy==1.3.1
cycler==0.12.1
dask==2024.10.0
datapi==0.1.1
dm-haiku==0.0.13
dm-tree==0.1.8
earthkit-data==0.10.9
earthkit-geo==0.2.0
earthkit-meteo==0.3.0
earthkit-regrid==0.3.4
eccodes==2.38.3
ecmwf-api-client==1.6.3
ecmwf-opendata==0.3.10
einops==0.8.0
entrypoints==0.4
exceptiongroup==1.2.2
fasteners==0.19
filelock==3.16.1
findlibs==0.0.5
flatbuffers==24.3.25
fonttools==4.55.0
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.10.0
GPUtil==1.4.0
graphcast @ git+https://github.com/deepmind/graphcast.git@97d1ad50b0b7af4aaed7790167dffa769bae1f2c
grpcio==1.66.1
h11==0.14.0
huggingface-hub==0.26.2
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.10
importlib_metadata==8.5.0
itsdangerous==2.2.0
jax==0.4.35
jax-cuda12-pjrt==0.4.35
jax-cuda12-plugin==0.4.35
jaxlib==0.4.34
Jinja2==3.1.4
jmespath==1.0.1
jmp==0.0.4
jraph==0.0.6.dev0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2024.10.1
kiwisolver==1.4.7
lit==18.1.8
locket==1.0.0
lru-dict==1.3.0
Markdown==3.7
MarkupSafe==3.0.2
matplotlib==3.9.2
mdurl==0.1.2
microsoft-aurora==1.4.0
ml_dtypes==0.5.0
mpmath==1.3.0
multiurl==0.3.2
netCDF4==1.7.2
networkx==3.4.2
numcodecs==0.13.1
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.4.5.8
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.4.127
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12==12.6.85
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.4.127
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.4.127
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==9.5.1.17
nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.2.1.3
nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.5.147
nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.6.1.9
nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91
nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.3.1.170
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.21.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12==12.4.127
nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
nvidia-nvtx-cu12==12.4.127
nvidia-pyindex==1.0.9
onnx==1.17.0
onnxruntime-gpu==1.20.0
opt_einsum==3.4.0
ordered-set==4.1.0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.2.3
partd==1.4.2
patsy==0.5.6
pdbufr==0.11.0
pillow==11.0.0
pooch==1.8.2
protobuf==5.28.3
pycparser==2.22
pydantic_core==2.4.0
pyparsing==3.2.0
pyproj==3.7.0
pyshp==2.3.1
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-multipart==0.0.9
pytz==2024.2
PyYAML==6.0.2
readchar==4.2.0
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==2.0.0
rpds-py==0.20.1
rsa==4.9
Rtree==1.3.0
ruamel.yaml==0.18.6
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.12
runs==1.2.2
safetensors==0.4.5
scipy==1.14.1
shapely==2.0.6
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.6
sympy==1.13.1
tabulate==0.9.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
timm==0.6.13
toolz==1.0.0
torch==2.5.1
torch-harmonics==0.6.2
torchvision==0.20.1
tqdm==4.66.6
traitlets==5.14.3
trimesh==4.5.2
triton==3.1.0
types-python-dateutil==2.9.0.20240906
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.2
urllib3==2.2.3
uvicorn==0.30.6
websocket-client==1.8.0
websockets==12.0
Werkzeug==3.0.4
xarray==2024.10.0
xmod==1.8.1
zarr==2.18.3
zipp==3.20.2

I ran python jax_test.py and expected the program to print an integer of how many devices jax has available.
I have tried different versions of Jax with commands like:
pip install -U "jax[cuda12]" and
pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
I have tried different versions of cuDNN
conda install -c nvidia cudnn=9.3 and
pip install nvidia-pyindex 
pip install nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 
pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu12

I have no clue what the next step should be to work on the issue.
Update: solved it.
With some outside help this issue was solved by installing specific versions of jax, the cuda toolkit and cudnn:
For Jax:
pip install "jax[cuda12]"==0.4.26 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
For Cuda, downloaded and installed 12.1 from their website:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-12-1-0-download-archive
For CuDNN:pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.1.23
